# Do neutrinos get their mass via interacting with the Higgs Boson?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Do neutrinos follow the Standard Model and get their mass via the Higgs Mechanism or we still don't know about the origin of their mass as neutrinos with mass are beyond the Standard Model?

Comment: here is a good answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45852/mechanisms-of-mass-generation-for-dirac-neutrinos

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw_mechanism